# what would be the Query in MS-Access for my following requirement?

Tags: c#, ms-access

i want to fetch all the records having max product id from product table. the records in the product table are stored as category wise like following

```
Product id  Category id Product name    Product image
    1           1        product 1          path
    2           1        Product 2          path
    1           2        Product 1          path
    2           2        Product 2          path
    3           2        Product 3          path
    1           3        Product 1          path
```

and i have Category table like following

Category id Category name
        1       Category 1 
        2       Category 2
        3       Category 3

so i need to write query that return all records of max product in each category (1,2,3 here in this example) so we'll get the result like

```
#    Product id  Category id Product name    Product image
1.       2           1        product 2          path
2.       3           2        product 2          path
3.       1           3        product 1          path
```

note:- product id is primary key and generated according to it's category 
       category id is foreign key in product table.
       i am using this query/database in my C# application. I am using **MS-Access.**

Comment: sorry i couldn't draw sql-like table in question please don't vote down the question because of that

Comment: Please verify that my edit kept your intentions.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Thank a lot for reformatting the question i really appreciate it

Comment: Question: Why is `product 1` shown with a lowercase `p` in one line and uppercase `P` in another line? Another question: Why is product #3 in the output listed with a name of `product 2`? (and why is the output in lowercase for `Product`?) Are these just mistakes?

Comment: it is just a record case doesn't matter!(it could be PRODUCT 1 or p 1 or LAYS or French Fries or anything) i dont get your 2nd question

Comment: Line 2 in the output says product id 3, but has the name "product 2". Is this supposed to be "product 3" as well?

Comment: If the first one is the product table, and you have a column product id, why aren't these id's unique?

Comment: YES its supposed to be Product 3 i am extremely sorry for that mistake i just need the max products from Product table from all the categories. i have updated my question adding my Category table but i failed to format it :/

Comment: id Generated According to its Category. Category 1 will have Products (id starting from 1 to n) ,Category 2 will have Product (id starting from 1 to n) and so on

Answer (score 0):

Ok this will help:

```
"SELECT * From Product WHERE Categoryid=(SELECT Max(Count(*)) from product group by Categoryid)"
```

Comment: it is the row(fields, record) retrieved from Product table mentioned above

Comment: so?is there any thing you would like to say?

Comment: so one is the category id?

Comment: yes i had mentioned "Category" table it has 2 fields Category_Id and Category_Name it currently has 3 category 1,2,3

Comment: like category 1 product id 3 product name product 1 and its path?

Comment: category table and Product table have 1 TO MANY relationship we can add n number of records in each category and i just need all max ones from each category

Comment: and path is the relative path of image :"~images/1.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

this should help

**SQL Server -**

```
select p.* from
(
   select max(productid) productid,categoryid from products group by categoryid
) a join products p on p.productid = a.productid
and p.categoryid = a.categoryid
```

**ACCESS -**

```
select [p].* from
(
   select max(productid) as pid,categoryid from products group by categoryid
) as [a] inner join [products] as [p] on [p].[productid] = [a].pid
and [p].categoryid = [a].categoryid
```

Comment: thank you so much for answering but this query throws syntax error :/ ( i think its because alias 'a' is not defined or something)

Comment: yes it runs fine in fiddle but when i apply it on my access database (query design) it throws syntax error in from clause. please note that i have 2 tables "product" and "category" please help (vote my question up if u can please) and thank you soo much for your time